# Error in attempting to parallel task of a bash script

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallel the task of `rpw_gen_features` in the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxjobs=8
jobcounter=0
MYDIR="/home/rasoul/workspace/world_db/journal/for-training"
DIR=$1
FILES=`find $MYDIR/${DIR}/${DIR}\_*.hpl -name *.hpl -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort -n -t _ -k 2` 
for f in $FILES; do
  fileToProcess=$MYDIR/${DIR}/$f
  # construct .pfl file name
  filebasename="${f%.*}"
  fileToCheck=$MYDIR/${DIR}/$filebasename.pfl
  # check if the .pfl file is already generated
  if [ ! -f $fileToCheck ];
  then        
    echo ../bin/rpw_gen_features -r $fileToProcess &
    jobcounter=jobcounter+1
  fi
  if [jobcounter -eq maxjobs]
    wait
    jobcounter=0
  fi
done
```

but it generates some error at runtime:

```
line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

I'm not an expert in bash programming, so please feel free to comment on the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `then`, spaces and `${}` around the variables:

```
  if [jobcounter -eq maxjobs]
    wait
    jobcounter=0
  fi
```

Should be

```
  if [ ${jobcounter} -eq ${maxjobs} ]; then
    wait
    jobcounter=0
  fi
```

Further, you need to double check your script as I can see many missing `${}` for example:

```
jobcounter=jobcounter+1
```

Even if you use the variables correctly this still will not work:

```
jobcounter=${jobcounter}+1
```

Will yield:

```
1
1+1
1+1+1
```

And not what you expect. You need to use:

```
jobcounter=`expr $jobcounter + 1`
```

With never versions of BASH you should be able to do:

```
(( jobcounter++ ))
```

Comment: @Rasoul You were also missing spaces and variable declarations.

Comment: You are right! I just fixed it. What do you think about the whole code? Is this the right way to parallel the task?

Answer (score 2):

I am curious why you don't just use GNU Parallel:

```
MYDIR="/home/rasoul/workspace/world_db/journal/for-training"
DIR=$1
find $MYDIR/${DIR}/${DIR}\_*.hpl -name *.hpl -type f |
  parallel '[ ! -f {.}.pfl ] && echo ../bin/rpw_gen_features -r {}'
```

Or even:

```
MYDIR="/home/rasoul/workspace/world_db/journal/for-training"
parallel '[ ! -f {.}.pfl ] && echo ../bin/rpw_gen_features -r {}' ::: $MYDIR/$1/$1\_*.hpl
```

It seems to be way more readable, and it will automatically scale when you move from an 8-core to a 64-core machine.

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.